# ASP.Net - Add header to dynamically created Excel file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, gridview

I am using the class GridViewExportUtil to export a GridView (gvMuster) to an Excel file. This is working fine, however I would like to be able to add a header (or some form of title etc.) to the generated Excel file but I am unsure how to do this.

Gridview is passed to the class in a button click as below:-

```
GridViewExportUtil.ExportToFile(("\\somepath\Muster\Muster.xls"), gvMuster)
```

The contents of the class are as follows:-

```
Public Shared Sub Export(fileName As String, gv As GridView)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName))
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel"


    Using sw As New StringWriter()
        Export(sw, gv)

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString())
        HttpContext.Current.Response.[End]()
    End Using
End Sub

Public Shared Sub ExportToFile(fileName As String, gv As GridView)
    Using streamWriter As New StreamWriter(fileName)
        Using sw As New StringWriter()
            Export(sw, gv)
            streamWriter.Write(sw.ToString())
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Public Shared Sub Export(sw As StringWriter, gv As GridView)
    Using htw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

        Dim table As New Table()

        table.GridLines = gv.GridLines

        If gv.HeaderRow IsNot Nothing Then
            GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(gv.HeaderRow)
            table.Rows.Add(gv.HeaderRow)
        End If

        For Each row As GridViewRow In gv.Rows
            GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(row)
            table.Rows.Add(row)
        Next

        If gv.FooterRow IsNot Nothing Then
            GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(gv.FooterRow)
            table.Rows.Add(gv.FooterRow)
        End If

        table.RenderControl(htw)
    End Using
End Sub

Private Shared Sub PrepareControlForExport(ByVal control As Control)
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Do While (i < control.Controls.Count)
        Dim current As Control = control.Controls(i)
        If (TypeOf current Is LinkButton) Then
            control.Controls.Remove(current)
            control.Controls.AddAt(i, New LiteralControl(CType(current, LinkButton).Text))
        ElseIf (TypeOf current Is ImageButton) Then
            control.Controls.Remove(current)
            control.Controls.AddAt(i, New LiteralControl(CType(current, ImageButton).AlternateText))
        ElseIf (TypeOf current Is HyperLink) Then
            control.Controls.Remove(current)
            control.Controls.AddAt(i, New LiteralControl(CType(current, HyperLink).Text))
        ElseIf (TypeOf current Is DropDownList) Then
            control.Controls.Remove(current)
            control.Controls.AddAt(i, New LiteralControl(CType(current, DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text))
        ElseIf (TypeOf current Is CheckBox) Then
            control.Controls.Remove(current)
            control.Controls.AddAt(i, New LiteralControl(CType(current, CheckBox).Checked))

        End If
        If current.HasControls Then
            GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(current)
        End If
        i = (i + 1)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Then what does this line of code do? `HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName))`

Comment: Sorry, I meant add header as in header/footer. It doens't even need to be a header as such, just a way of adding a title above the exported gridview in the Excel document

Comment: @Jimsan Can't you simple add a first row to your GridView with a header text in cell?

Comment: Hi Yuriy, each column already has a column header. I would like to add some form of title above the GridView which will appear on the Exported Excel file.